# How avoid the use of switch cases (with dll functions) c#

Tags: c#, dll

I use a DLL to communicate with a bootloader through a Microchip and I use many functions of the dll.

```
Swicht(DLL Function)
case: Readbyte
    MC2211.readbyte(intptr DeviceHabdle, unit number Of Bytes, ref Data)
case : Writebyte
    MC2211.readbyte(intptr DeviceHabdle, unit number Of Bytes, ref Data)
```

But this kind of structure goes against the open close principle.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Could you edit your question to address the concrete way in which you would like the open-close principle to be fulfilled by your code? In particular, I'd be interested to know who is expected or supposed to "modify" your code (presumably by adding more DLL functions) while it remains "closed" (i.e. presumably without recompiling your assembly). Do you somehow want to load the list of available functions in the DLL at runtime or anything like that?

Comment: By the way, your `Writebyte` case invokes something called `readbyte` - intentional or a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

```
interface IMC2211Command
{
    void Run( object[] args );
}

class ReadByteCmd : IMC2211Command
{
    public void Run( object[] args )
    {
        // read bytes
    }
}

class WriteByteCmd : IMC2211Command
{
    public void Run( object[] args )
    {
        // write bytes
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
IMC2211Command cmd = new WriteByteCmd();
cmd.Run( args );
```

It will make all your command is adding codes rather than changing existing switch cases.